How do I create template categories in org roam?
I have the following code in the config block of my use-package for Org-roam:
  (setq org-roam-capture-templates
        (list
     (my-org-roam-capture-template "d" "default" "%?")
     (my-org-roam-capture-template "l" "programming language"
                           "* Characteristics\n\n- Family: %?\n- Inspired By:\n\n* Reference:\n\n"
                       "Programming")
     (my-org-roam-capture-template "p" "project"
                                       "* Goals\n\n%?\n\n* Tasks\n\n** TODO Add initial tasks\n\n* Dates\n\n"
                                       "Project")
     (my-org-roam-capture-template "t" "textbook"
                                       "~/Desktop/Roam/Templates/TextBookTemplate.org"
                                       "Textbook")
     (my-org-roam-capture-template "f" "framework"
                       "~/Desktop/Roam/Templates/FrameworkTemplate.org"
                       "Programming")))

(my-org-roam-capture-template is a function I made to reduce the boilerplate when adding in new roam templates)
I want to add two more templates for textbook chapters and textbook chapter sections. I know that I could just add in new templates, but I was hoping that there was some functionality that, after using org-roam-node-find, would allow me to type a key and see more templates, like with how org-capture-templates works.
Here's an example of that for org-capture-templates:
(setq org-capture-templates
      `(("t" "Tasks / Projects")
    ("tt" "Task" entry (file+olp "~/Desktop/Orgfiles/Tasks.org" "Inbox")
     "* TODO %?\n  %U\n  %a\n  %i" :empty-lines 1)

    ("j" "Journal Entries")
    ("jj" "Journal" entry
         (file+olp+datetree "~/Desktop/Orgfiles/Journal.org")
         "\n* %<%I:%M %p> - Journal :journal:\n\n%?\n\n"
         ;; ,(dw/read-file-as-string "~/Notes/Templates/Daily.org")
         :clock-in :clock-resume
         :empty-lines 1)))

I'm aware that I could probably create some wrapper function that would allow me to choose specific templates, but I'm not very good at Emacs Lisp, and I'm hoping that I'm just missing some key functionality.

I have not tried it but reading the doc string for org-roam-capture-templates, multi-key entries work in exactly the same way as in org-capture-templates: `keys   The keys that will select the template, as a string, characters only, for
example "a" for a template to be selected with a single key, or
"bt" for selection with two keys. When using several keys, keys
using the same prefix must be together in the list and preceded by a
2-element entry explaining the prefix key, for example:
               ("b" "Templates for marking stuff to buy")`


@NickD Oh... well that's embarrassing. I saw that when I was reading around and just got confused- thanks for the help.
